# what's the simplest way to create a div table with a centered header?

Tags: html, css

I need to create a div table (display:table, table-row, etc) with a centered header on top and a 1px border all the way around.  What is the simplest way to do this?

Comment: Please provide some code that you tried so we have a better understanding of what you're trying to do and can help you

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Stack Overflow is not a coding service. You have to put atleast some effort to solve your own problem, before others are willing to help. Please check out how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 1):

What's a div table? It's either a div or a table.

Anyways sounds like you need to do some reading: https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_tables.asp

Below you see I just added `align="center"` and `colspan="2"` to the th element. Change the colspan to however many columns you have to center the th.

**HTML**

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <th align="center" colspan="2">header</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Hello</td>
        <td>Hi there</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

The borders just add to the CSS:

**CSS**

```
table {
   border: 1px solid black;
}
```

Example codepen: https://codepen.io/StefanBobrowski/pen/WpByzg

Answer (score -1):

Twitter bootstrap is one of the best frameworks which saves a lot of time to create web pages. There are so many tags to get done things quickly. Please give a try to go through it.

http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/

Comment: What does this have to do with making a table? You don't need a whole framework for that, plus Bootstrap makes your code seriously ugly.